# Inspect Realm proxy objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, realm, realm-object-server

In javascript I am using this function

```
export async function createNewRealm(name) {
  if (process.env.REALM_DISABLED === 'true') return Promise.resolve();
  if (!connectionAdminUser) await establishRealmConnection();
  console.log(`Creating ${name} at realms://${server}/${name}`);
  return Realm.open({
    sync: {
      user: connectionAdminUser,
      url:  `realms://${server}/${name}`
    }
  });
}
```

Upon calling the function like this

```
  let test = await realm.createNewRealm('test');
  console.log(test);
  console.log(test.empty);
```

I get following output

```
Creating test at realms://:SNIPPED/company-test
Connection[1]: Session[1]: client_reset_config = false, Realm exists = true, async open = false, client reset = false
Connection[1]: Connected to endpoint ':SNIPPED' (from ':SNIPPED')
Connection[1]: Disconnected

Realm {}  <-- THIS being first console.log
true      <-- THIS being second console.log

Connection[2]: Session[2]: client_reset_config = false, Realm exists = true, async open = false, client reset = false
Connection[2]: Connected to endpoint ':SNIPPED' (from ':SNIPPED')
```

Now I get that this is because `test` in `let test = await realm.createNewRealm('test');` is not proper javascript object, but proxy object.

**What I would like to know - How can I inspect in code the content or at least see the keys via console.log?**

The documentation [here](https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest/api/Realm.html#.open) can be used, but I did notice that it is not always updated and I would like to avoid context switching by having to look every time if it is `user.id` or `user.identity`, etc...

So is there JS way to get those to output via console.log? I don't mind if it ends up being string, or array, just to be able to see the content of various realm objects on demand.

*Also bonus question, in the log from realm itself I can see `Realm exists = true`, but there is nothing in documentation saying if I can see that via object being returned. So far I am checking if it is new by calling `test.empty`, is there an easier way? (related since this is the reason why I am asking main question)*

Answer (score 0):

I dont have right env, but try this code

```
 let test = await realm.createNewRealm('test');
 console.log(test.__proto__);
```

I think you can print all properties like this

```
for(let n in test)  console.log(n,' = ',test[n]);
```

Comment: It's to big to paste in comment, but doesn't help much. Here is what I get: https://pastebin.com/mUyk5MWJ